# Third-party clients that work with Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

For specialized Android devices that may be unable to (or may not need to) run the full suite of Google Services, are there any 3rd party clients that would work with GCM?

Alternatively, is this something that can be developed?

Note, this is not a question about *alternatives* to GCM. We would like to work with GCM.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you are looking for a library/framework to implement push notifications etc. in your app then how about [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/)?

Why don't you just want to use GCM? I don't think there are any lirbaries/frameworks which enable GCM without using Googles libraries. I know a lot of wrappers like for example [node-gcm](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm) or [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) but at their core they all rely on Googles solution and do not use a custom client with their own libraries.

Comment: No, I wasn't looking for alternatives like Urban Airship. There are situations where not running Google Services is the preferred option--product capabilities, licensing constraints-- and my question relates to one of those.